# Getting Started with Durandal

Tags: javascript, durandal

I'm interested in building a SPA application. From what I can tell, Durandal provides the majority of what I'm looking for. Except, I'm looking for the most basic possible example that uses durandal. The sample app that's included uses bootstrap and sammy.

Is Bootstrap and Sammy required? If not, is there a sample I can see somewhere that doesn't have the code? I just want a basic app with two screens to use as an example. Yet, I can't seem to find the bare minimum example anywhere.

Thank you,

Comment: I would just use the compose bindinghandler to start with.  http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/
As you get familiar with that you can start exploring the other modules durandal has.  But the power of durandal comes from the Compose module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.20 of Durandal uses Sammy.js for routing if you include the optional router plugin.  It is not necessary, but a pretty good idea to use it to simplify learning Durandal without having to learn how to route.

Durandal 2.0 is scheduled for release this month that gets rid of Sammy.js's dependency and has it's own router.

To find an example or sample app using Durandal that doesn't rely on either Sammy.js or Bootstrap will be difficult because they are easy to include, everyone understands them, and it's hard to go wrong when using these to simplify a sample app.

If you are looking for a very simple sample you can look up John Papa's CodeCamper JumpStart, but it includes a lot of other dependencies.  The Durandal Starter Kit however is available on nuget and from durandaljs.com and has a single view and is an excellent way to start learning Durandal.js.